Unable to install Ubuntu Server on MacBook because of resolution issues
I have an old MacBook (2017) laying around, which I wanted to convert to Ubuntu Server. Unfortunately, the installer is larger than the actual screen!
During install this was annoying, but I think I got all settings right... However, after booting the fresh install and running a couple of commands, I noticed that I still can't see all output, as part of my output and the cursor disappeared from view at the bottom of the screen.
Is there a way to rescale both the installer and (if the setting isn't saved during the install) the installed OS to have a usable computer? Or am I forced to install the Desktop version?
